# Alternatives to Appcache

Tags: html5-appcache

I am developing a site using PHP, and I was a bit mislead by how Appcache works; it turns out that it also caches the current page. Which, in the case of a PHP app, is a problem. :)

I'd still like to cache my javascript, css and images on the client, but not my actual generated page. What is a good alternative for that? Just the plain old cache headers? The problem I see with them is, that they still produce requests. I am trying to mimize the amount of requests a client needs to make - this includes `304`s.

Comment: What do you consider "old" tags ? ETag ? cache-control ? expires ? There are a lot of means to tell a browser how long to cache a file without requesting something from the server. Don't get fooled by a network trace of your browser. Some request might be listed there although they never reach the server. To be sure check the access logs of your server.

Comment: @Marged I've used the network tab within the Chrome Developer Tools to look up whats happening - and I'd always see 304s going to my server, and indeed hitting it as well. That's why I'm trying to find means to reduce requests to my server, optimally being only requests for the main page.

Comment: Like I said: are you sure that these 304 are really reaching your server ? Have you checked the server logs ?

Comment: @Marged They indeed reach the server, yes. I double-checked.

Comment: Then it is time to answer my question about the tags. Which do you use ? A screenshot of incoming and outgoing http headers for one of the mentioned resources would help.

Answer (score 2):

As you might have found out by now, appCache is [in the process of being deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Using_the_application_cache) and will sometimes disappear. It was a good solution for offline applications (static pages with variable data), but not as a cache for static files in dynamic pages.

You could try to include a blank page with a manifest in a hidden iframe in your dynamic pages, but still only pages present in the appCache would use the static resources downloaded from the manifest; the other pages would check the live static resources from the server anyway (the only part of the manifest which is valid everywhere is the "fallback" part).

So your best option is to check your cache headers as suggested by Marged, as it IS possible to avoid server access indefinitely for a static resource.

You could dig what the [ServiceWorkers cache](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Cache) does, but I'm not an expert in the field (for now).